# Reference algorithm/formula for the distribution of the median of random variables?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, random-variables, order-statistics, median

The distribution of the mean of two random variables can be calculated using a convolution. I have a collection of $n$ independent random variables each with PDFs that are simple functions on $[0,1]$. I would like to know the exact distribution of the median of these variables. I understand there is a [central limit theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45124/central-limit-theorem-for-sample-medians/76096#76096) for the distribution of the sample median for i.i.d variables, but I don't have that assumption here. I also see that there's a [way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664063/probability-distribution-of-the-median) to get a formula for *discrete* random variables. Is there a reference for continuous random variables?

Comment: The median is a particular order statistic, and there's a general formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Cumulative_distribution_function_of_order_statistics ... ah, but you don't have the iid assumption? (The link to the discrete case uses that assumption.)

Comment: Are the variables independent, at least?

Comment: @IgorRivin They are independent. Fixed. They are not identically distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number of your random variables is $2n,$ the probability that the median is $x$ equals
$$m(x)=\sum_{\mbox{subsets I of size $n$}}\prod_{i \in I} F_i(x) \prod_{j\notin I}(1-F_i(x),$$ where $F_k$ is the CDF of the $k$-th variable. Needless to say, for $n$ large (as in, bigger than about 6), this is not super useful. If the variables are $i.i.d,$ this is a fairly civilized formula.

Comment: Haha, maybe this is a bad direction. Do you think Monte-Carlo would be useful to look at?

Comment: This suggests a dynamic programming approach for calculating this that is better than the naive sum: https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2021/03/18/on-the-distribution-functions-of-order-statistics/ @Zach466920

"It turns out that we can evaluate the exponential-size sum in O(nk) time with a simple algorithm, which is essentially a probabilistic generalization of the dynamic program for evaluating the binomial coefficients. Furthermore, we can evaluate the distribution function for all n order statistics in O(n2) time. The code for doing this computation is below."

Comment: @LorenzoNajt Cool!